# Subtlety regarding Rouche's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a complex polynomial $f(z)=z^7+z^5-z^4-6z^3-z^2+1$,
find the number of roots in $|z|<1$.

Now it's clear that for $g(z) = 6z^3$ one can use Rouche's theorem.

However, in order to apply it we must show that $f$ has no zeros on $|z|=1$ which doesn't seem trivial.

Answer (score 5):

You have $|f(z)+g(z)| \le 5 < 6 = |g(z)|$ for $|z|=1$. If $f(z) = 0$ for some $|z|=1$, then this would be a contradiction.